# Prove that set of Rubik's cube rotations equipped with composition forms a group.

Tags: group-theory, rubiks-cube

Tl;dr: I am trying to show intuitively that the set of Rubik's cube rotations forms a group. (I am not talking about literal rotation of the cube, but, of the edges.)

The group axioms it must follow are:

1. Associativity: Three actions applied in the succesions (ab)c and a(bc) are same.
2. Identity action
3. Inverse action for any action in the group

The second and third are pretty easy to see. But, how do I see that Rubik's cube rotations are associative under composition?

Comment: You can think of the Rubik's cube moves as functions: label each of the 36 squares on the cube by some number. A move just bijectively maps the 36 squares to 36 other squares. So it's some element of $S_{36}$.

Comment: @Mathmo123: ... except that there are 8 movable squares on each face, so it's $S_{48}$.

Comment: @HansLundmark Right of course - a cube has six faces :)